# No applications list in KMenu

Tags: kubuntu

Since last update I can't find any application in *Applications* tab in KMenu applications launcher and also no applications in *open with* context menu. Is there a way to say (K)ubuntu to recreate/build applications list?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

**Update:**

Executing KDE utility ***kbuildsycoca4*** solved the problem for me. Thank you user26687!

Comment: The KDE has the kbuildsycoca4 command. An example with the OpenBox window manager: http://askubuntu.com/questions/262888/how-to-get-openbox-as-kdes-window-manager

Comment: Excellent! It works! I'll add this to the question description. Thank you!