# How to get Openbox as kde's window manager

Tags: 12.04, kde, menu, openbox

I successfully installed Openbox on my laptop running Kubuntu 12.04
but when I login using the kde/openbox session, the desktop icons of kde, show me an
"open with ?" pop up, while the kmenu is almost empty and isn't showing any application entries (only leave, command, or favorites).

I couldn't find a way until now to establish a correct behaving of kde/openbox, so I would like to know where to find the method for configuring this.

Answer (score 1):

**Testing**

Installing the openbox.

Making a new user.

Log in as the new user.

[image]

The KDE Menu is empty.

[image]

**Trying to fix**

Running the kbuildsycoca4 to rebuild the system configuration cache.

```
:~$ kbuildsycoca4 --help
Usage: kbuildsycoca4 [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [options] 

Rebuilds the system configuration cache.

Generic options:
  --help                    Show help about options
  --help-qt                 Show Qt specific options
  --help-kde                Show KDE specific options
  --help-all                Show all options
  --author                  Show author information
  -v, --version             Show version information
  --license                 Show license information
  --                        End of options

Options:
  --nosignal                Do not signal applications to update
  --noincremental           Disable incremental update, re-read everything
  --checkstamps             Check file timestamps
  --nocheckfiles            Disable checking files (dangerous)
  --global                  Create global database
  --menutest                Perform menu generation test run only
  --track <menu-id>         Track menu id for debug purposes
```

There is an error - missing files.

[image]

Starting the Dolphin file manager with the root rights (kdesudo dolphin).

Browsing to the /etc/xdg/menus/. There is the kde4-applications.menu but not the applications.menu.

Making a softlink / symlink from the applications.menu to the kde4-applications.menu (KDE drag&drop menu "link here").

[image]

[image]

Running the command:

```
kbuildsycoca4 --noincremental
```

again...

The KDE menu is now populated with the available applications.

[image]